# Proving that Schrödinger equation is a Hamiltonian system

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

*When the (informal) SE $$\frac{d}{dt}\psi(t) = -iH\psi(t)$$ is to be solved numerically, you want to preserve the total probability $$|\psi(t)|^2 = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \psi_i(t)\bar{\psi}_i(t)$$ (ie for it to be constant in time). $\bar{\psi}_i(t)$ is the complex conjugate of $\psi_i(t)$, $H$ is a constant symmetrical real $N \times N$ matrix and $\psi(t) \in \mathbb{C^n}$ is the wave function at time $t$. Show that the (informal) SE is a Hamiltonian system.*

**Attempted solution**

The definition states that a system of ODEs
$$\begin{cases} \frac{dx}{dt} = f(x,y) \\  \frac{dy}{dt} = g(x,y) \end{cases}$$ has a Hamiltonian if $$\frac{\partial f}{ \partial x }= - \frac{\partial g}{ \partial y}$$
Let $x(t) = \psi(t)$ and so $f(x,y) = iHx(t)$. Since the total probability is constant in time we get:

$$\frac{d}{dt} |\psi(t)|^2 = 0 \leftrightarrow 2\psi(t)\psi'(t) = 0 \leftrightarrow -2iH \psi(t) \cdot \psi(t) =0 \leftrightarrow |\psi(t)|^2=0$$
**Question**

Is this the correct approach and if so how can I continue?

Comment: I am not very familiar to such problems, but a hint: No. $(12)$ in http://cdn.intechopen.com/pdfs/43877/InTech-Schro_dinger_equation_as_a_hamiltonian_system_essential_nonlinearity_dynamical_scalar_product_and_some_ideas_of_decoherence.pdf looks somehow like your equation; hope this script can help you.

Comment: @Lozansky I'm taking a Numerical Methods course (in a CS program which does not include any physics so Hamiltonian systems are new to me) and I have been stuck in pretty much the same place as you for more than a day. I imagine you have solved the problem by now, would you be able to give some sort of hint to help me move forward? Were you on the right track for example?

Looking at equation at the bottom of your question, I don't understand the last step where you get $\|\psi(t)\|^2=0$ but perhaps that's not important if you ended up taking another route. Thanks!